# What was Prof. Sub Zero a professor of in The Running Man?

Tags: the-running-man

In the distopian future of "The Running Man" there was a deadly Asian assassin known for slaying his targets in arctic conditions named Sub Zero.

The future's Justice Department controlled television and in the eponymous popular TV show, Sub Zero was referred to as being a Professor. Are there any details on this (if not from the movie then perhaps a book or elsewhere)? What was he supposed to be a Professor of?

**For Clarification**

*Not this one*

[image: Sub Zero]

*This one*

[image]

Comment: So weird that I was thinking of this movie last night, and here's a question. But, I don't think the character was in the book, or meant to be an actually professor of anything but murder.

Comment: I read the story about 25 years ago, and I don't remember much, but I don't think the movie has anything in common with it beyond the title and the fact that people die as part of a game show involving convicts.  I don't remember any corny themed gladiators like this guy.  Also, he's clearly a professor of attaching blades to hockey sticks.

Comment: Which *The Running Man* are you asking about? I was trying to write the tag wiki excerpt, but there are [several films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_Man) with that name.

Comment: @WadCheber: indeed, the movie and the book have almost nothing in common.  They both involve a TV show, but the TV show in the book is completely different: no themed gladiators, no game zone, volunteers instead of convicts.  Oh, and some of the characters in the movie have the same name as characters in the book.  That's about it.  (I thought the movie was better, but Stephen King fans might disagree.)

Comment: @amarillo I didn't realize that. The one with the former Governor of California as the main actor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Out-of-universe

Professor Sub Zero was played by [Charles J. Kalani Jr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_Tanaka), who was known as Professor Tanaka in his wrestling career. Professor was a common title for a judo master, as [this thread](http://www.e-budo.com/archive/index.php/t-17199.html) attests. Although Kalani was a wrestler, he trained under a judo master, or indeed judo *professor*, for a time.

### In-universe

It's probably something similar. The games in *The Running Man* are similar to professional wrestling – a game with predetermined outcomes which everyone believes to be legitimate. It makes sense that people would have titles ("Professor," "Dyanmo," "Buzzsaw") that don't necessarily have a relation to their day jobs. Indeed, being stalkers in the game probably *is* their day job.

Alternately, perhaps "Professor" is meant to suggest mastery, just as with real-life judo.